# Output thread id with breakpoint "commands"

Tags: gdb

I know how to view threads info with `info threads`, but now I want to print them in a breakpoint command.

Is that possible?

e.g

```
break XX
commands
printf "tid=%d, item1=%s, item2=%d ...\n", some_command, a, b
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Search the manual for the "$_thread" convenience variable.  It holds the current thread number.